# C# Can't read a XML Array and the Nodes within

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to read the following response. **The green line states the node I need to read**:

**I need to read the 3rd 'result' item ALWAYS**

[image]

My Code:

```
            string location = "";

            string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&sensor=true";

            XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
            doc1.Load(url);
            XmlElement root = doc1.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse[0]");


            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                location = node["formatted_address"].InnerText;
            }
```

The code doesn't give me any nodes in fact the the Node count is 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to check `nodes` variable? Does it contain any values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in Xpath expression. To get all ther result nodes use this:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result");
```

If you want only the third result node you can use [SelectSingleNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var node = root.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result[3]");
location = node["formatted_address"].InnerText;
```

**Update**

The initial problem is in you url.You forgot `latlng=` part. This is an example of working url:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true
```

Also there could be a problem with number format, if your sytem properties have `,` as a double delimeter. You can use `InvariantCulture` to solve this. So the working example would be:

```
double latitude = 40.714224;
double longitude = -73.961452;
string url = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng={0},{1}&sensor=true", 
    latitude, 
    longitude);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(url);
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
var node = root.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result[3]");
var location = node["formatted_address"].InnerText;
```